# How ram addresses are differentiated from memory map address

Tags: memory-management

I was trying to understand the boot process and memory management on arm and had question related to memory map addresses and ram address.

- What I understand:

Every Soc will have a memory map and size depends on the addressing capability, ex: a 32 bit processor has addressing capability of 2^32 or 4GB. A memory map will contain address of different peripherals mapped and vector table e.t.c ex: address 0x00000000 is reset vector, address 0x70000000 is UART registers, and so on.

Similarly a DDR controller will also have a memory mapped address to control the RAM.

- My Question:

Assuming size of the RAM as 4GB, how does the address 0x70000000 of RAM is accessesd without effecting the memory map (or UART registers) ?

Please correct my understanding if I have misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: it's not accessible. Memory-mapped peripherals take precedence over RAM at the same address.

The most famous example is actually Win32, where video cards are memory-mapped and often reduce available RAM to 3.5GB.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 concepts here. The **address space**, which is determined by the system address bus width, and the actual **hardware** that back the address space. The actual hardware can be real memory, like DDR5. Or it can be various other hardware types that claims a certain range of address space. The host CPU just access them in a uniform load/store way.

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100014/how-does-the-operating-systems-get-a-memory-map-of-the-x86-pc-despite-several-ch):

> Not all the physical address space is backed by RAM. Some of it is
> mapped to device control registers, video memory etc. Basically there
> are to types of memory mappings, the virtual memory mappings set up by
> the OS which maps process memory to physical memory (or swap). And and
> the chipset which maps addresses on the data-bus to RAM or devices.

According to [here](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2004/readings/i386/s08_01.htm):

> I/O devices also may be placed in the 80386 memory address space. As
> long as the devices respond like memory components, they are
> indistinguishable to the processor.
>
> Memory-mapped I/O provides additional programming flexibility. Any
> instruction that references memory may be used to access an I/O port
> located in the memory space.
>
> Memory-mapped I/O performed via the full instruction set maintains the
> full complement of addressing modes for selecting the desired I/O
> device (e.g., direct address, indirect address, base register, index
> register, scaling).